# Add custom properties to objects before alembic export

Tags: alembic, custom-attributes

I want to add custom properties on objects and export them with alembic, then read them from another software.
like in maya `AbcExport -j .. - attr foo -attr bar ..`

Answer (score 0):

I write a function to do this:

````
    name = validate_name(name)

    class CustomProperty(bpy.types.PropertyGroup):
        custom_property: bpy.props.StringProperty(name=name)

    mesh_data = mesh_obj.data

    mesh_data[name] = value
    bpy.utils.register_class(CustomProperty)
    bpy.types.Mesh.my_properties = bpy.props.PointerProperty(type=CustomProperty)```

a reference file to useful blender functions [Djed][1]


  [1]: https://github.com/Michaelredaa/Djed
````